# Visual Studio 2017 Chrome JavaScript Debuging - Not hitting break point

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have installed VS2017 and trying out the new stuff they added. One of the nice things is chrome JS debugging but I can't seem to hit a break point.

I created a new .net core website (.net core 1.1) and add the following function into the site.js file

```
function test() {
var a = "message";

console.log(a); };
```

I then add a break point on the line "var = a..."

run the website - it opens a new chrome window and attaches to the process like it should. I then press F12 and call test() but no break point is hit it just outputs to the console.

One thing that is also in the console window is the following message -

> Browser Link: Failed to invoke return value callback:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null

however i also get this message when trying it out in IE11 and it does hit the break point in IE

I have updated my chrome to the latest version - 57.0.2987.98
I am running windows 10 pro (fully up to date)

[image: site.js code]

[image: Chrome Console Output]

Any ideas what it might be?

## Update

I have tried on the following computers -

1. My home PC (Windows 10 Pro)- has VS2015 and VS2017 on it
2. Work PC (Windows 8.1 Pro) - also has VS2015 and VS2017 on it
3. With in my work PC - (new build) HyperV VM (Windows 8.1 Pro) - just VS 2017 on it

All 3 failed to hit the break point

Whats odd is someone else at work **is** able to make it work without an issue.

Comment: Be sure to run Visual Studio as administrator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you hit F12 in chrome, which opens the Chrome Dev Tools, it kills the client-side debugging session.

See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

Perhaps try executing automatically... e.g... (untested)

```
(function test() {
   ...
})();
```

Comment: Well this makes the tooling worthless tbh but yes it was this... oddly it would not hit a breakpoint in the self invoking function but does in a normal function - (function test() {
    showSomething();
})();

function showSomething() {
    var a = "Message";
    alert(a);
}

Comment: It breaks in a self-executing function for me: you need to refresh the browser once however, it won't do it immediately on F5.  As for not having the Chrome dev tools open, I think the point is that you can't attach the two debuggers to the same code in the same debug session.  So you either debug with Chrome's excellent debug tools, or you debug with Visual Studio's excellent debug tools, not both at the same time.  Which doesn't seem entirely unreasonable.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I **closed chrome browser** and ran the application again then set the break point inside my `.js` file and now it hits. Also if you have tabs open with same application running in tabs then debugger wont hit for some reasons.

Comment: "Which doesn't seem entirely unreasonable.....unless you want to look at the console logs while debugging...

Answer (score 0):

Prior to V 63 of chrome, it would not allow multiple remote debugging sessions. Opening the chrome debug tools would take over the only available connection, and terminate the one held by VS.

However this has now been rectified by the chromimum team !

Unfortunately there is still a problem with the Visual Studio debugging session getting terminated when F12 is hit.

There is a workaround, and hopefully the VS team will correct the underlying issue. See [My post on MSDN for full details](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5cd1aa58-d986-4d03-a10e-bf1fd62080a7/simultaneous-debugging-in-chrome?forum=vsdebug)